# How do I "slow down" an ImageView in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a "Snapping" Horizontal scroll view class that extends HorizontalScrollView. What I wish is to apply a parallaxing effect  to an underlying ImageView on this ScrollView so that, if the user scrolls the view 2px to the right, the imageview moves 1px to the left. So basically it will look like the background image is moving slightly slower than the rest of the layout.

How do I accomplish this? I expect that the logic required to do this is to be written in onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Translate Animation using your onTouch.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this library:
https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView